# ArrayList Issue

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I have two values, `small_red` and `small_blue`:

```
private EnemyInfo small_red = new EnemyInfo("Red Fighter", Core.jf.getToolkit().createImage(Core.class.getResource("/com/resources/ENEMY_01.png")), 10, 100, new Location(0, 0), false, 0);
private EnemyInfo small_blue = new EnemyInfo("Blue Fighter", Core.jf.getToolkit().createImage(Core.class.getResource("/com/resources/ENEMY_02.png")), 50, 100, new Location(0, 0), false, 0);
```

and an ArrayList:

```
private ArrayList<EnemyInfo> activeEnemies = new ArrayList<EnemyInfo>();
```

Let's say I add three of the `small_red` and five of the `small_blue` enemies into the `activeEnemies`.  Whenever I want to change a variable inside the array, e.g.:

```
activeEnemies.get(1).setActive(true); // change one of the small_red enemies
```

*every* `small_red` in the array is changed, instead of just the one at index `1`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're adding 3 references to the **same** smallRed enemy each time to the arraylist.

To explain;

```
private EnemyInfo small_red; //I am a variable, I hold a reference to an EnemyInfo

new EnemyInfo(.....) //I create a new EnemyInfo object "somewhere" and return a reference to it so it can be used.
```

`small_red` can be considered a memory address (although its more complicated than that), so you're adding the same memory address several times (like adding the same house address to your real life address book). It doesn't matter what page you get the address from in your address book; letters go to the same house.

Every time you use the `new` keyword you are creating a new instance of an object, otherwise you're just passing around a reference to an old object.

Comment: @Gosre Glad I could help, the idea of references to objects is one of the harder concepts to get when going from "primitives" which are always copied when passed to a function and objects where only the references are copied