# Weird behaviour with java loops

Tags: java, loops, shuffle

The output I get for this is :

```
Inside loop : [5, 6, 3, 1, 4, 2]

Inside loop : [3, 1, 5, 6, 4, 2]

Inside loop : [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3]

Inside loop : [5, 2, 6, 4, 3, 1]

Outside loop : [5, 2, 6, 4, 3, 1]

Outside loop : [5, 2, 6, 4, 3, 1]

Outside loop : [5, 2, 6, 4, 3, 1]

Outside loop : [5, 2, 6, 4, 3, 1]
```

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class PossibleSolution {
    // the indices of where to place the cuts to delimit routes (different
    // vehicles)
    int[] indicesCut;
    // the set of ordered Customers for each route. Routes delimited by cuts
    ArrayList<Integer> OrderedCustomers;
    // length of array
    int size;

    // Constructor
    public PossibleSolution(int[] indices, ArrayList<Integer> Customers) {
        this.indicesCut = indices;
        this.OrderedCustomers = Customers;

        this.size = Customers.size();
    }

    // method to generate the neighborhood for one possible solution. We need a
    // parameter
    // to specify the number of neighbors to generate

    public PossibleSolution[] generateNeighborhood(int number) {
        PossibleSolution[] sol = new PossibleSolution[number];
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            java.util.Collections.shuffle(this.OrderedCustomers);

            sol[i] = new PossibleSolution(this.indicesCut, this.OrderedCustomers);
            System.out.println("Inside loop : " + sol[i].OrderedCustomers);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            System.out.println("Outside loop : " + sol[i].OrderedCustomers);
        }

        return sol;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> Customers = new ArrayList();
        Customers.add(2);
        Customers.add(4);
        Customers.add(5);
        Customers.add(1);
        Customers.add(6);
        Customers.add(3);
        int[] ind = { 2, 3 };
        PossibleSolution initialSol = new PossibleSolution(ind, Customers);
        PossibleSolution[] table = initialSol.generateNeighborhood(4);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the question? what should the code do? could you explain what you expect on the output?

Answer (score 4):

All of your `PossibleSolution`s reference the same `ArrayList`.

(All of your `ArrayList` variables and fields are pointing to the single `ArrayList` that you created in `main()`. So, every time you shuffle the list, it affects the list values everywhere. If you want `PossibleSolution()` to capture a snapshot of the state of the list as it was when it was called, you need to make a copy.)

Comment: To expand, the OP needs to use a .clone() or Collections.copy method in his PossibleSolution constructor so that they reference distinct data structures.

Answer (score 1):

#### Summary

The constructor does not copy Customers, it just stores a reference to it. As such if you pass a reference to one object to several `PossibleSolution`s then **they will all share it**

```
public PossibleSolution(int[]indices, ArrayList<Integer> Customers){
    this.indicesCut = indices;
    this.OrderedCustomers = Customers; //<-- Only the reference is copied, not the object

    this.size = Customers.size();
}
```

#### Explanation

```
for(int i =0; i<number;i++){        
        java.util.Collections.shuffle(this.OrderedCustomers);

        sol[i] = new PossibleSolution(this.indicesCut,this.OrderedCustomers);
        System.out.println("Inside loop : "+sol[i].OrderedCustomers);
    }
```

All `PossibleSolution`s share the same `this.OrderedCustomers`, as such whenever you shuffle `this.OrderedCustomers` you are changing the internals of all the `PossibleSolution`s

So its not suprising that this prints the same thing over and over again

```
for(int i=0; i<number;i++){
   System.out.println("Outside loop : "+sol[i].OrderedCustomers);
}
```

because its the **same** OrderedCustomers

#### Solution

If you want a copy, then you need to ask for a copy of the object, not just the reference, the easiest way to do this is to use [System.arrayCopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29):

```
System.arraycopy(from, 0,to,0,from.length);
```

#### Further reading

A simplified version of this same 'references to the same object in different places' problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18742268/2187042)

#### Other notes

`OrderedCustomers` and `Customers` are both variables, as such they should be lowerCamelCase; `orderedCustomers` and `customers`

Answer (score 0):

All the print statements labeled "Outside loop" are performed over the same array all the times. You're not randomizing anything anymore after getting out of the first `for` loop. You're just printing time and again.