# How do we iterate in a LinkedList in java when LinkedList is of type user-defined objects?

Tags: java

I am trying to print out the contents of the objects that were added to the linked list. In this code my expected o/p is: 100 20 300 but I get: 300 300 300. Where I am going wrong?

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.*; 
import java.io.*; 


class Body{ 
 int i; 
 public void setB(int i){ 
 this.i = i; 
 } 
} 
class Ideone 
{ 
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception 
  { 




  Body b = new Body(); 
  Body bdum; 

  LinkedList<Body> l = new LinkedList<Body>(); 

  b.setB(100); 
  l.add(b); 

  b.setB(20); 
  l.add(b); 

  b.setB(300); 
  l.add(b); 

  Iterator<Body> li = l.iterator(); 

  System.out.println(l.size()); 
  System.out.println("List is:"); 

  while(li.hasNext()){ 
  bdum = li.next(); 

  System.out.println(bdum.i); 
} 

} 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ArrayList Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742268/arraylist-issue)

Comment: a side note, also consider overriding `equals` method in the `Body` class, it is required when you compare between `Body` objects stored in the list. if you override `equals` override `hashCode` as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a single `Body` object and add it three times to the list. You should create three different objects instead. That is:

```
b.setB(100); 
l.add(b); 

b = new Body();
b.setB(20); 
l.add(b); 

b = new Body();
b.setB(300); 
l.add(b);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
b.setB(100); 
l.add(b); 

b.setB(20); 
l.add(b); 

b.setB(300); 
l.add(b);
```

You're using the same object reference on the variable `b`. You should at least create a new object reference and assign the values, then add it to your list.

A possible solution may be:

```
b.setB(100); 
l.add(b);

b = new Body();
b.setB(20); 
l.add(b); 

b = new Body();
b.setB(300); 
l.add(b);
```

Another solution may be having a constructor in your class that will set the `i` field in your `Body` class:

```
class Body{ 
    int i; 
    //added for compatibility with current code
    public Body() {
    }
    public Body(int i) {
        setB(i);
    }
    public void setB(int i){ 
        this.i = i; 
    } 
}
```

Then in your class you just add a new instance of `Body` directly:

```
//b.setB(100); 
l.add(new Body(100));

//b.setB(20); 
l.add(new Body(200)); 

//b.setB(300); 
l.add(new Body(300));
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
  Body b = new Body(); 
  Body bdum; 

  LinkedList<Body> l = new LinkedList<Body>(); 

  b.setB(100); 
  l.add(b); 

  b.setB(20); 
  l.add(b); 

  b.setB(300); 
  l.add(b);
```

You may think that you have added 3 items into `LinkedList` but actually there is only one item being added into List since you're re-using same object reference multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing value on same instance of `b`. You need to create different instance and set values like:

```
   Body b1 = new Body(); 
   b1.setB(100); 
   l.add(b1); 

   Body b2 = new Body(); 
   b2.setB(20); 
   l.add(b2); 

   Body b3 = new Body(); 
   b3.setB(300); 
   l.add(b3);
```